# How did database queries handle case sensitive queries prior to the Lower()/Upper() sql functions?

Tags: sql, odbc

I have the privledge of working with a REALLY old database. This database was built sometime in the 80s. The APP that manages it is a DOS app that the company I work for still uses. I started a project with them to build them a new app and give them a new up to date database. This old one is an ODBC database.

I need to make case insensitive queries on it and it seems that lower() and upper() functions do not work at all on this database.

I wonder if there are any SQL coders here who've been in the business long enough to know what, if anything, database programmers did to get around case sensitive queries prior to these functions?

Or if there is an easy way to bring this huge old database up to the 21st century that would be nice too. I'm new enough to SQL as it is and this old database has me stumped.

Comment: ODBC is a way of connecting to any db - what is the database you are using

Comment: ODBC was introduced around 1990. There is a difference between the case-significance of the code and that of the data. "old" DBMS-s were intended to store and retrieve data, not to change its case. IF SOMEONE WANTED TO PUT DATA INTO THE DATABASE IN all-caps, HE SHOULD BE ABLE TO DO SO11

Answer (score 1):

Were you using something like "select lower(column)" and did you try the ODBC syntax "select {fn lcase(column)}".

Answer (score 0):

You mention ODBC...

If you can connect to this database's tables (via ODBC) with...SQL-Server, for example, then you can use the modern UPPER() and LOWER() functions available through TSQL / SQL-Server.

You shouldn't need to manipulate the data using the old system's DML functions.

Comment: well okay I guess I'm lost then. I posted a question earlier today because I cannot use upper() lower() functions. It claims they are undefined functions. I thought it was because it was an older DB.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is (to use SSMS for example), if you can open SSMS and then ODBC *connect* to your old database, you should be able to run SELECTS against it (still in SSMS) using modern functions.  If you're using the old database manager, however, then you're going to be stuck with whatever DML it can understand (from the 1980's...).  Hope that makes sense.  Let me know if I'm missing something...

Comment: Well I've currently got it connected to Visual Studio 2010. And that's where I'm running the queries through.